# How to require.resolve the package directory?

Tags: node.js

`require.resolve('babel-runtime')` returns an error because its `package.json` does not contain a "main" field. However, I'm not interested in the main/entry file of the package, I want to get the directory of the package itself.

Usually that's located at `${__dirname}/node_modules/babel-runtime`, but it might not be if the `node_modules` tree is flattened. So how can I resolve the directory of a package the same way Node knows where to look when you write something like `require('babel-runtime/core-js/object/create')`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It occurred to me that if Node can resolve file paths even when "main" doesn't exist, then I can abuse that like so:

```
 path.dirname(require.resolve('babel-runtime/package.json'))
```

i.e., resolve a file that you know to exist, and then work backwards from there. Kind of a hack, but it's the only solution I've found.

Comment: this actually fails when the package has "exports" field, saying:
`Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports"`

Comment: @UriKutner That feels like a Node bug.

Comment: Sounds like a safety feature (a private/public thing)

Answer (score 1):

same as the solution above, I found you can do slightly better with

```
import findRoot from 'find-root';

findRoot(require.resolve('babel-runtime'))
```

still hacky, but will work even if package.json is not in the `"exports"` field.

that said, actually this would fail for babel-runtime.. huh.. so it won't work for the original question